# Sandbox org TLS 1.1 update breaks outbound calls

Tags: callout, exception, tls

This morning, our team arrived to find our sandbox instance in disarray. Salesforce had disabled TLS 1.0 across the entire instance, breaking our homegrown applications that communicate with it via APIs, as well as outbound connections to third parties (for things like account lookups). We've fixed our .NET applications -- it was actually pretty easy!

However, the APEX code we're using to do outbound SOAP calls to 3rd parties are still broken. In one instance, we have:

```
WebServiceCallout.invoke(
    this,
    request_x,
    response_map_x,
    new String[]{endpoint_x,
        'findCustAccts',
        'http://webservice.findcustaccts.CLIENT.com',
        'findCustAccts',
        'http://webservice.findcustaccts.CLIENT.com',
        'findCustAcctsResponse',
        'CLIENT_webserviceFindcustaccts.findCustAcctsResponse_element'}
);
```

Here's what it looks like in the log when I fire this off:

```
System.CalloutException: IO Exception: Server chose TLSv1, but that protocol version is not enabled or not supported by the client.
```

Nowhere in the documentation does it state how to 'force' a certain TLS level. What can we do to make these servers play nice?

Note: I have seen [Callouts to web services started failing with CalloutException: Server chose TLSv1](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/111912/callouts-to-web-services-started-failing-with-calloutexception-server-chose-tls) and that does not solve this problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately it is up to the external service to negotiate the connection and support tls 1.1

> The general compatibility guidelines from the API (inbound)
>   integrations (see section above) can be used to help achieve TLS 1.1
>   and later compatibility. **However, since the technologies and vendors
>   used to run the remote endpoints can vary, the teams that manage the
>   endpoints will need to work to achieve TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2
>   compatibility on the end points that they run.**

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000221207

Comment: But...shouldn't we be able to set the outbound handshake protocol to one that is supported? It seems like the industry standard is changing and we should be able to make *outbound* callouts using an up-to-date protocol.

Comment: @AdrianLarson - The communication is negotiated. SF Says to remote - We do not do 1.0, we can do 1.1, remote service says, we do not do 1.1 we do 1.0, sf says sorry. Basically if the remote service supports 1.1 it will negotiate to it. If they use multiple, it will negotiate to a common protocol. Basically if the service only uses 1.0 then SF will not connect to it

Comment: Ah, I interpreted OP as saying SF was using 1.0 and instead 1.1 or 1.2 would be preferred. I get it now.

Comment: Indeed. Qualys rates them 'F' -- they don't support 1.1 or 1.2. Boo -- I've contacted them.